# VBA: How to find the department and replace it with another department?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulty find a solution to this problem. I am trying to find the string `department` and replace it with some another department. There are **16-10 sheets** in each workbook that needs formatting. One of the formats requires moving/copying the `first department string` (which reaches out to into `columns B,C` in some rows) and pasting it where the `last department` was but the first department in some sheet in `columnA` doesn't have a department above it but `member number`. The reason is for this it to make the department a title.

The picture in the bottom should provide more information.[image]

This is what I have so far but doesn't comply. I would appreciate some help on this.
Please ask questions and give suggestions. Thank you.

```
    Sub format()

       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim frstDept As Long
       Dim lastDept As Long
       Dim rng As Long
       Dim n As Long
       Dim nlast As Long
       Dim rw As Range
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim iVal As Integer
       iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A20000"), "Department")
       Debug.Print iVal

        Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        nlast = rw.Count

        For Each ws In Sheets
            On Error GoTo NextWS
            For i = iVal To 1 Step -1
                With ws
                        frstDept = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Department", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Row
                        lastDept = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Member Number", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Row
                            If .frstDept.Value = .lastDept.Value Then
                            frstDept.Selection.Offset(0, 2).Cut Destination:=Range("lastDept" + 1).Resize(1)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
     NextWS:
                Err.Clear

                Next ws

       End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K no it doesn't because it says invalid qualifier but it works in `format`

Comment: Actually, the whole methodology is flawed, because you are going to find the first occurrence of the strings over and over again.  You will need to at least change the code to perform a find `After` a certain row.  Is your intended outcome to set columns A:C of any row which has "Member Number" in column A of the row below equal to columns A:C of the row above the next "Member Number"?

Comment: @YowE3K yes I understand but I am not sure how to add the `after` feature...

Comment: @YowE3K my intended outcomes is to have `Department..` in place of the  previous `Department..` but for the very first `Department..` there is no `Department..` above it so that is confusing how would I write to code that includes all of these conditions.

Comment: Is the last record in column A always a "Department"?

Comment: @YowE3K yes sir, however it appears in the picture.

Comment: Your picture doesn't show the last record in column A.  (Unless the "------" is the last record, and that isn't a "Department".)

Comment: @YowE3K no sir, it is always a `Department...` on everysheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following code will work:

```
Sub format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lastDept As String
    Dim nextDept As String
    Dim rw As Long

    For Each ws In Worksheets ' Changed from "Sheets" to "Worksheets" to avoid
                              ' problems if any "Charts" exist
        With ws
            rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'Grab the details of the last "Department" and then clear the cells
            lastDept = RTrim(.Cells(rw, "A") & .Cells(rw, "B") & .Cells(rw, "C"))
            .Range("A" & rw & ":C" & rw).ClearContents

            For r = rw To 2 Step -1
                If Trim(.Cells(r, "A").Value) = "MEMBER NUMBER" Then
                    nextDept = RTrim(.Cells(r - 1, "A") & .Cells(r - 1, "B") & .Cells(r - 1, "C"))
                    .Range("A" & r - 1 & ":C" & r - 1).ClearContents
                    .Cells(r - 1, "A").Value = lastDept
                    lastDept = nextDept
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Every time it finds "MEMBER NUMBER" in column A, it grabs the information from columns A:C of the row above, then clears those cells, and replaces column A with the concatenated values from the previous time it had encountered a "MEMBER NUMBER".  (I'm assuming that concatenating columns A:C into one string is a good thing.  If not, I can edit it so that the values are kept as separate strings.)

---

Edited to search for "Department" (with a reliance on row 1 always being blank).

```
Sub format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lastDept As String
    Dim nextDept As String
    Dim rw As Long

    'Initialise "lastDept" to blank so that the first replacement we make
    '(i.e. the one on the last row) is to an empty value        
    lastDept = ""
    'Loop through every worksheet
    'Use "Worksheets" collection rather than "Sheets" collection so that
    'we don't try to do any processing on Charts ("Sheets" contains both
    'Worksheet and Chart objects)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'Use a "With" block so that we don't have to constantly write
        '"ws.Cells", "ws.Range", "ws.Rows", etc - we can just use
        '".Cells", ".Range", ".Rows", etc instead
        With ws
            'Find the end of the data by finding the last non-empty cell in column A
            rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'Loop (backwards) through each row in the worksheet
            For r = rw To 1 Step -1
                'We only need to process something when Column A starts with
                '"Department", or if this is row 1 (which will be empty)
                If Left(.Cells(r, "A").Value, 10) = "Department" Or r = 1 Then
                    'Temporarily store the current values of this row's columns A:C
                    'Join all three cells into one string to make it look "nicer"
                    nextDept = RTrim(.Cells(r, "A").Value & _
                                     .Cells(r, "B").Value & _
                                     .Cells(r, "C").Value)
                    'Clear out what was in A:C
                    .Range("A" & r & ":C" & r).ClearContents
                    'Write the contents of "lastDept" into column A
                    .Cells(r, "A").Value = lastDept
                    'Change "lastDept" to be the value which we stored in our
                    'temporary variable "nextDept" (The temporary variable was
                    'needed because, by the time we get to this line, we have
                    'written over the top of the information in the worksheet
                    'cells.)
                    lastDept = nextDept
                End If
            Next ' end of processing of a row
        End With
    Next ws ' end of processing of a Worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: It works but there is a small issue. One sheet has a big account and it is `department 75`. its accounts last until `department 70`. It is hundreds of lines in between. So `department 70` has to go all the way at the top and `department 75` needs to go to the place where `department 70` was.

Comment: @MTBthePRO Let me guess - there are multiple "MEMBER NUMBER" lines within the one department?

Comment: Is the first "MEMBER NUMBER" always in row 2?  Or can that first one be identified because it is the only "MEMBER NUMBER" with a blank cell above it?

Comment: Yes it is always in row 2 and column a. there is always space above it.

Comment: Question. Does the `lastDept` contain `department` or is `nextDept`

Comment: Is possible that you can briefly summarize what's going on..I am having a hard time reading it.

Comment: Thank you very much like always :)

Comment: @MTBthePRO `lastDept` contains the department.  So does `nextDept`.  But `nextDept` is just a temporary variable so that we can hold the current value of row `r` while we clear it and write `lastDept` into the row.  If we just wrote `lastDept` in without first saving the current value, we would end up with the same department in all sections.

Comment: @MTBthePRO - I have to go to a meeting now - I will try to add a bit more in the way of explanation later this morning (or maybe when I get home from work - about 8 hours time)

Comment: Interesting. great that would be awesome.

Comment: @MTBthePRO - Second part of answer now includes more comments than code.  Hope that helps you to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting frstDept to a row, same with lastDept. I believe you intend to instead set these to a range. Try this:

```
Sub format()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim frstDept As Range
   Dim lastDept As Range
   Dim rng As Long
   Dim n As Long
   Dim nlast As Long
   Dim rw As Range
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim iVal As Integer


    Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    nlast = rw.Count

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate

        iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A:A"), "*Department*") 
        Debug.Print iVal
        On Error GoTo NextWS
        For i = iVal To 1 Step -1 ' You dont have a next statement closing this for loop.
            With ws
                    Set frstDept = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Department", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    Set lastDept = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Department", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                        If .frstDept.Value = .lastDept.Value Then
                            lastDept.Offset(-1, 0).Value = frstDept.Offset(1, 0).Value

                        End If
                    End If
            End With
 NextWS:
            Err.Clear

            Next ' This should close the for loop for your iVal iteration.
        Next ws

   End Sub
```

Also, both of your find statements are the same, and in theory should return the same range. I can't make sense of why you are using the same find statement from your question, so I don't have a suggestion on how to improve it.

The code above likely won't solve your problem, but it should get you closer. My best bet is that your On Error statement has been activating every time you tried to get the vale of your firstdept and lastdept variables, and so it hasn't been doing anything.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You will need to remove the `.` in front of `.frstDept` and `.lastDept` - those are variables (objects) in the code, not Methods or Properties of the `ws` worksheet object.  (And, IIRC, you will need to select the worksheet before selecting a range within that worksheet.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had updated my code just before you posted your answer. I found another issue, my iVal isn't counting the departments.

Comment: Good catch YowE3k, I completely missed those.

Comment: And your `Resize(-1)` won't work - you can't have a range with `-1` row in it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that one, so I didnt touch it. Changed it to work better.

Comment: Edited the iVal  code to properly count instances of department within a ws.

Comment: it still is not counting departments because `Debug.Print iVal` displays `0` Would it have to with departments not being on its own? it's usually department 32 adult crop

Comment: I added wildcards "*" around department, try that.

Comment: lol it iVal works, may i know what a wildcard does? @BrandonBarney

Comment: A wildcard basically tells the code that anything can exist there. By putting it on both sides the code is just checking that the string between the wildcards exists.